# With Me You Will Never Leave. What Am I?

Tags: riddle

> I produce many offspring, although all are hidden from view.
>
> Unless we wrestle, you tug, I break, and then you will see a few.
>
> At first sight they seem strangely clear, although very deep red.
>
> In Turkey I've seen people throw my friends to the ground,
>
> Although I understand, it is always meant as good-will.
>
> But also, I have a dark side
>
> That some people do know
>
> With one of my stones you will never leave.
>
> No matter how hard you believe.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Is the answer a

> Pomegranate?

because

> It seems to fit the "You'll Never Leave Part..." like in the Persephone myth.

Wait this puzzle is kind of weird though

EDIT #1:

I produce many offspring, although all are hidden from view.

> Offspring are the pomegranate seeds. There are a lot of them.

Unless we wrestle, you tug, I break, and then you will see a few.

> Uh...when you rip off the fruit from the tree?

EDIT #2:
At first sight they seem strangely clear, although very deep red.

> I don't know why they seem clear...they are supposed to be very red.

In Turkey I've seen people throw my friends to the ground, // Although I understand, it is always meant as good-will.

*Finally got this one yay :D*

> When Turkish people want to make a New Year wish, they smash a pomegranate on the floor of their front door exactly at midnight for good luck for the year. Thanks @Lafexlos for this part :D

Comment: @Lafexlos Thank you so much! I'll immediately fix my answer. Don't want it to be wrong, and want to respect the tradition :D Thanks!